# Can't get WordPress featured image to display on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to get featured images to display for each post on my category page: https://insider.uprighthealth.com/category/exercise-library/

I have featured images set on all the posts, but am not sure what theme file I need to modify in order to display the featured images. (Running a child theme over Canvas and woocommerce)

Any help would be much appreciated, I am sure this is an easy fix for a php guy!

Best,
-M

I can't find a category.php file but have listed the archive.php below

```html
<?php
/**
 * Archive Template
 *
 * The archive template is a placeholder for archives that don't have a template file. 
 * Ideally, all archives would be handled by a more appropriate template according to the
 * current page context (for example, `tag.php` for a `post_tag` archive).
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

 global $woo_options;
 get_header();
?>      
    <!-- #content Starts -->
 <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="col-full">
    
     <div id="main-sidebar-container">    
  
            <!-- #main Starts -->
            <?php woo_main_before(); ?>
            <section id="main" class="col-left">
             
   <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' ); ?>
                    
            </section><!-- /#main -->
            <?php woo_main_after(); ?>
    
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    
  </div><!-- /#main-sidebar-container -->         

  <?php get_sidebar( 'alt' ); ?>       

    </div><!-- /#content -->
 <?php woo_content_after(); ?>
  
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

content-archive-portfolio.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * "Portfolio" Content Archive Template
 *
 * This template is the used to display "portfolio" posts when in a generic archive.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

/**
 * Settings for this template file.
 *
 * This is where the specify the HTML tags for the title.
 * These options can be filtered via a child theme.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters
 */

 $title_before = '<h1 class="title entry-title">';
 $title_after = '</h1>';

 if ( ! is_single() ) {

  $title_before = $title_before . '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => 0 ) ) . '">';
  $title_after = '</a>' . $title_after;

 }

 $page_link_args = apply_filters( 'woothemes_pagelinks_args', array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'woothemes' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) );

 woo_post_before();
?>
<article <?php post_class( 'post' ); ?>>
<?php
 woo_post_inside_before();
?>
 <header>
  <?php the_title( $title_before, $title_after ); ?>
 </header>

 <section class="entry">
     <?php
      echo '<div class="fl portfolio-img">' . woo_image( 'return=true&key=portfolio-image&width=100&height=100' ) . '</div><!--/.fl-->' . "\n";
      the_excerpt();
      wp_link_pages( $page_link_args );
     ?>
 </section><!-- /.entry -->
<?php
 woo_post_inside_after();
?>
</article><!-- /.post -->
<?php
 woo_post_after();
 comments_template();
?>
```

loop-archive.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * Loop - Archive
 *
 * This is the loop logic used on all archive screens.
 *
 * To override this loop in a particular archive type (in all categories, for example), 
 * duplicate the `archive.php` file and rename the duplicate to `category.php`.
 * In the code of `category.php`, change `get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' );` to 
 * `get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );` and save the file.
 *
 * Create a duplicate of this file and rename it to `loop-category.php`.
 * Make any changes to this new file and they will be reflected on all your category screens.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
 global $more; $more = 0;
 
woo_loop_before();
if (have_posts()) { $count = 0;

 $title_before = '<h1 class="archive_header">';
 $title_after = '</h1>';
 
 woo_archive_title( $title_before, $title_after );
 
 // Display the description for this archive, if it's available.
 woo_archive_description();
?>

<div class="fix"></div>

<?php
 while (have_posts()) { the_post(); $count++;

  woo_get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );

 } // End WHILE Loop
} else {
 get_template_part( 'content', 'noposts' );
} // End IF Statement

woo_loop_after();

woo_pagenav();
?>
```

Comment: can you show some code as to what you have tried?

Comment: A little more detail here would be useful to get you the help you're after quicker. Perhaps add a list showing the directory structure of the Canvas theme so that someone could point you to the correct file. If I had to hazard a guess I would say that either `category.php` or `archive.php` is the file you're looking for. I'm not familiar with Canva specifically but some themes have options to output images on categories - you can usually find them in the main options panel or exposed in the customizer.

Comment: @WilliamPatton Just added in the archive.php file from canvas to my original post

Comment: @Progidge Can you share the file `content--archive.php` please?

Comment: @ConnorGurney sorry for the slow response, just added it in

Comment: @Prodige Just reading through it now, no worries.

Comment: @ConnorGurney Hey no rush, but did you see anything in there?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this in **loop-archive.php**

Comment: Just added the file to my original post

Comment: So we going in to one more circle now you should search for **content-post.php** for post, **content-page.php** for page, **content-CUSTOM_POST_TYPE.php** for custom post type. Inside in them you can add `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $, $attr ); ?>` in to content-post.php you can add this after `<div class="entry">` in line 47.